# Change all file type associations from one program to another

Tags: windows-7, file-association

Is it possible to easily change all file type associations that are currently associated with one program to another program in one batch?  In my case, I am trying to change all files types currently associated with Notepad to instead use Notepad++ in Windows 7.

It's a pain to go through `Default Programs > Set Associations` because after each type the entire list re-populates, taking several seconds.  Is there a way I can do a search and replace in the registry, or something even easier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In many programs you can set file types associated with the program itself from settings. For example in Notepad++ you can go to Settings -> Preferences and select tab File Association. There you can add files that should be associated with notepad++.

This is not direct answer to what you asked but it should accomplish the same task. In case the program you want to set associations with doesn't have this option you will have to use your method.

Answer (score 9):

T. Kaltnekar's answer is fine for this program, but [**Default Programs Editor**](http://defaultprogramseditor.com) can do this for any program and any context menu action for any number of extensions.

Open the program, click `File Type Settings`. The search box, in addition to searching extensions and descriptions, supports limited advanced queries, in the format `<verb>:<application>`, where "verb" means the item on the file type's context menu, and "application" is the program that item launches when clicked.

So in your case, you'd search for `open:notepad` to get a list of all file types that Open with Notepad:

[image: Search file types by program]

You can then select all the items you want out of that list (Ctrl+Click, Shift+Click or Click+Drag like normal) then hit `Next`.

On the Context Menu page, click the item you want to edit (`Open` in this case) and click `Edit Selected Command`. Then you're on this page, where you put in the path to the program of your choice. For you, this is Notepad++ (`%1` is the parameter you pass the program so that it opens the file you've clicked. It's a common Windows thing):

[image: Edit a verb for multiple file types]

Then `Next`, `Save Context Menu`, and you're done.

Comment: Please have a look at your images ;-)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a quite handy software called [FiletypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) that's very convenient to have around when dealing with filetypes.

Comment: Not as useful as it could be - it does not allow reassigning multiple entries at once. I hoped I would just select all associations of one image viewer and reassign them all to another, but nope. I'm supposed to edit each of ~30 associations manually.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could [make Windows think it's using Notepad](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/04/replace-notepad-with-another-text-editor-eg-notepad2-and-notepad-in-vista/), when in fact it's using Notepad++.  Basically you rename notepad++.exe to notepad.exe and place the executable in the appropriate directories.

Edit: [more extensive instructions](http://coster3.com/2008/04/20/make-notepad-your-default-editor/)

Comment: +1 Interesting, and at this point I'm willing to entertain the idea.  But I'd *really* rather simply modify the associations, if it's possible to do easily.

Comment: Actually, it's better to use the Image File Execution Options trick. Much easier to revert, and no need to fool windows' file protection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome icon does not show up against htm and html files in Windows Explorer – Solution

1. Open [FileTypesMan.exe](http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) (Freeware from Nirsoft)
2. It will list all file types registered on the computer.
3. Select htm file type. It will list all actions pertaining to that file type eg. Open, and also Edit and print shown as &edit and &print.
4. Ensure that all actions (including edit and print) are linked to chrome. exe. If not, then change default program to chrome exe.
5. Repeat steps for html file type.