# Somehow I have made my downloads of a certain file type auto-open in MPC. How can I change this?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](https://superuser.com/questions/29717/associate-a-file-type-with-a-specific-program)

I use MuseScore, a music notation program. Somehow Media Player Classic is the program automatically selected to open my .mscz files rather than MuseScore. I can still open these files from within MuseScore, but when I click on a .mscz file, MPC comes up. How can I change this?

Comment: Related: [Change All File Type Associations from One Program to Another.](http://superuser.com/questions/41609/change-all-file-type-associations-from-one-program-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some programs are able to manage associations themselves (i.e. IrfanView), which can be easier.  Refer to MuseScore documentation on whether it's able to do that.

Otherwise:

1. Right-click the file
2. Choose *"Open With"* -> *"Choose Program..."* (do not choose your program even if it's already on the list)
3. Choose your program from the list OR use *"Browse..."* button to browse for the executable
4. Check *"Always use the selected program..."*
5. Click OK

If there's no "Open With" in the context menu, try holding *Shift* before right-clicking (IIRC, that's how it worked in older versions of XP).

Comment: Thanks @Alois. I was able to do it by going to the properties menu and changing it there. +1 and accept.