# Is it possible to entirely replace one app from another in all defaults?

Tags: file-association, file-extension

Let us say I want to replace PowerPoint with another presentation software for all the extensions it is currently the default application (.pptx,.ppt,.ppsx, etc.). Is it possible to do that all at once (without uninstalling PowerPoint)?? (I am running Windows 10.)

Answer (score 0):

[Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) can do this for any program and any context menu action for any number of extensions.
See also the detailed [step-by-step guide](https://superuser.com/a/41955/1464400) how to solve your task.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.